# Count within a formatted DateTime with LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I populate the following List from database, where I like to get the percentage of Good or Bad by only day (ignoring time).

I cannot group the data by `data.GroupBy(p => p.DateTime.ToString("YYYY-MM-dd"))` or `String.Format("YYYY-MM-dd", p.DateTime)` or count from it, let alone doing the .Where clause to match a Content to be Good or Bad and count from it.

It is even possible in LINQ?

I can use SQL where I had to format each DateTime, perform multiple Array and Unique conversion and multiple SQL calls to retrieve the count for each variables to calculate a ratio, but that is so dumb.

```
DateTime                    Content
-------------------------------------
2018-03-16 17:59:26.000     Good
2018-03-16 18:05:04.000     Bad
2018-03-16 19:23:26.000     Bad
2018-03-17 03:19:02.000     Good
2018-03-17 06:20:32.000     Bad
```

**What I want to get**

```
2018-03-16   Good: 33%   Bad: 66%
2018-03-17   Good: 50%   Bad: 50%
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `data.GroupBy(p => p.DateTime.Date)`

Comment: Hi did any of these solutions solve your problem? or if you managed to solve this another way, please consider adding your solution and marking it as the correct answer for future readers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to take advantage of `DateTime.Date`

[DateTime.Date Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets the date component of this instance.

**Given**

```
var list = new List<MyClass>()
               {
                  new MyClass()
                     {
                        Content = "Good",
                        MyDateTimeField = DateTime.Now
                     },
                  new MyClass()
                     {
                        Content = "Good",
                        MyDateTimeField = DateTime.Now
                     },
                  new MyClass()
                     {
                        Content = "Bad",
                        MyDateTimeField = DateTime.Now
                     }
               };
```

**Group By**

```
var results = list.GroupBy(x => x.MyDateTimeField.Date)
                  .Select(x =>
                              {
                                 var count = x.Count();
                                 var good = x.Count(y => y.Content == "Good");
                                 var bad = x.Count(y => y.Content == "Bad");
                                 var result = new
                                                {
                                                   Date = x.Key,
                                                   Good = good / (decimal)count,
                                                   Bad = bad / (decimal)count
                                                };
                                 return result;
                              });

foreach (var item in results)
{
     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Date = {0}, Good = {1:P2}, Bad = {2:P2}", item.Date.Date, item.Good, item.Bad));
}
```

**Output**

```
Date = 3/24/2018 12:00:00 AM, Good = 66.67 %, Bad = 33.33 %
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cTn2oO)

**Note** : i'm using [Format Specifiers in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e514eeby.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) `P2` to format the percent, however you can apply your own rounding and logic to tidy it up

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
var result = from p in dataContext.Table
             group p by p.DateTime.Date into g
             select new { 
                 Date = g.Key, 
                 NumberOfGood = g.Count(p => p.Content == "Good"), 
                 NumberOfBad = g.Count(p => p.Content == "Bad"), 
                 PercentageGood = ((decimal)g.Count(p => p.Content == "Good") / ((decimal)g.Count(p => p.Content == "Good") + (decimal)g.Count(p => p.Content == "Bad"))),
                 PercentageBad = ((decimal)g.Count(p => p.Content == "Bad") / ((decimal)g.Count(p => p.Content == "Good") + (decimal)g.Count(p => p.Content == "Bad"))) 
             };
```